# Javascript Require.js dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, requirejs

if I have 2 .js files (A.js, B.js) and each of them has their own dependencies.

A depends on: C.js, D.js, E.js
B depends on: C.js, F.js, G.js

A and B have C as common dependency. If both A and B are loaded with Require.js, will the C.js be loaded twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C.js will only be loaded once, as long as it's loaded using the same name in A.js amd B.js.

Another useful thing you can do is as follows:

```
 require.config({
     "paths": {
         "C": "/somewhere/js/C-v1.0.0.js"
         }
     });
```

If you then require A and B, in A and B you can:

```
 require(["C"], function(C) {
 }
```

This way, if the location or version of C changes, you only have to change it in one place.

Comment: thanks! One more thing though, when it has executed the intended code, does it unload the script or does it keep it till the pages closes?

Comment: The script is available until the page closes.